# How to create releases for public or private repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, version-control, version, release

I have a problem how create releases in our public or private repository in GitHub ? How to do it using windows cmd or linux terminal ? Is there any special commands for that?

Comment: Maybe, this should help you https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/.

Comment: @ julian salas Thank you very much . The article you provide is very informative!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The example below show You how to made a single release cycle, first you should create a central repository, then you create a develop branch.

**You create a develop branch**

`git branch develop`
`git push -u origin develop`

This branch contain the complete history of your project, now whereas your  `master` contain new version. Your team should now clone the central repository and create a tracking branch for develop.

**You create a tracking branch for develop**

`git clone ssg: //user@/path/`
`git checkout -b develop origin/develop`

Everybody now has a local copy of the historical branches set up. So You decide to make a new feature. For that you create separate branches for your respective features with base as your develop branch.

**You begin a new feature**

`git checkout -b some-feature develop`

You can to add commits to the feature branch as You wish, then:

```
git status
git add <some-file>
git commit
```

**You finish your feature**

After adding new features, You decides that your feature are ready, now You can merge it into your local `develop` and push it to the central repository, like so:

```
git pull origin develop
git checkout develop
git merge some-feature
git push
git branch -d some-feature
```

The first command makes sure the develop is up to date before trying to merge in the feature. Note that features should never be merged directly into `master`.

**You begin to prepare a release**

While others develop's working on his feature, You can start to prepare the first official `release`  of project, You can to use a new branch to encapsulate the release preparations. This step is also where the release's version number is established:

```
git checkout -b release-0.1 develop
```

This branch is a place to clean up the release, test everything, update the documentation, and do any other kind of preparation for the upcoming release. It’s like a feature branch dedicated to polishing the release.

**You finish the release**

Once the release is ready to ship, You merges it into master and `develop`, then delete the release branch.It's important to merge back into `develop` because critical updates may have been added to the release branch and they need to be accessible to new features. Like so:

```
git checkout master
git merge release-0.1
git push
git checkout develop
git merge release-0.1
git push
git branch -d release-0.1
```

You should know that release branches act as buffer between feature development and public releases. Is good idea that whenever you merge something into `master`, you should tag the commit for easy reference:

```
git tag -a 0.1 -m "Initial public release" master
git push --tags
```

If you want a better explanation, visit this link: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow.

Comment: This is great! .I'll be check your solution as soon as possible and thank you again. This is what I want !

Comment: Aha! I've confused about the git checkout command and your answer has great explanation about that!

Answer (score 10):

Releases are a feature of GitHub, and are not a feature of general `git` (similar to other Github extra features like Issues and Pull Requests).  However, people have created projects that allow you to create GitHub releases from the command line.  The following are a few that I could find:

1. Go (golang) Implementation of GitHub releasing: https://github.com/aktau/github-release
2. JS Implementation of GitHub releasing: https://github.com/ungoldman/gh-release

Comment: Thank you very much for the info . This is interesting and really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

> How to do it using windows cmd or linux terminal ? Is there any special commands for that?

There is, using the GitHub CLIP `gh` that you need to [install first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation).

Since [`gh` 2.19.0 (Nov. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.19.0), you can do, using [`gh create release`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create):

> Support explicitly marking a Release as "`Latest`" by [@mislav](https://github.com/mislav) in [#6538](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6538)
>
> Example:
>
> ```bash
> cd /path/to/local/repository
> gh release create v1.3.0 --latest --target=main --notes ""
> gh release create v1.2.1 --latest=false --target=1.2-stable --notes ""
> ```

This helps considering since Oct. 2022, you can [explicitly set the latest release](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-21-explicitly-set-the-latest-release/) to any version you want.

> Previously, a repository's latest release was the one created on the most recent date. In the event that multiple releases had the same date, the semantic version number broke the tie.
>
> This new feature provides an explicit toggle to mark a release "latest" when you create it.